# Is there an easy one activity sample to integrate Play Services leaderboards and achievements in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, achievements, google-play-developer-api

I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio and I found difficult to embrace dependencies system in gradle files, expecially to integrate leaderboards and achievements system. 
Is out there some simple sample with only one simple activity to integrate leaderboards and achievements for Play Services?

Comment: I would recommend to first try starting with [Firebase Android app samples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) to get a feel of the SDK. Then checkout [Integrate With Your Play Games Services Project](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/integrate-play-games) to know how to unlock achievements and track scores on a leaderboard.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing but recently have been able to put together a simple one activity one layout example by combining the [Get Started With Google Play Games Services](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-google-play-games-services--cms-27755) tutorial from [Ashraff Hathibelagal](https://github.com/hathibelagal) and the [TypeANumber](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) tutorial from Google.

The android application is titled TapAttack and can be found on [Github](https://github.com/MDodd423/TapAttack).

This is my first Stack Overflow answer, I hope I have been helpful, Good Luck.